# How to select or join two ngrx entities in angular?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I have two entities that are related 1 to 1: Loads and Moves.
The load object contains the load_id and the move object contains the load_id. When displaying in the UI, it will use an *ngFor loop to display the combined object.

```
export interface LogisticsState {
    plans: fromPlan.State;
    loads: fromLoad.State;
    moves: fromMove.State;
}

export const getPlansState = (state: LogisticsState) => state.plans;
export const getMoveState = (state: LogisticsState) => state.moves;
export const getLoadState = (state: LogisticsState) => state.loads;
```

**my selecters**

```
export const getMoveEntities = createSelector(getMoveState, fromMove.getEntities);
export const getLoadEntities = createSelector(getLoadState, fromLoad.getEntities);
export const getSelectedMoveId = createSelector(getMoveState, fromMove.getCurrentMoveId);
```

In my component, I have two observables listening on the move and loads seperately.

I'm trying to write a createSelector to return a new object that contains the combined object/entity.

Note: I don't want to combine them in the store because on this particular page it is read only like a report, but on another component the will be editing seperatly.

**Initial approach**

```
export const getLoadByMoveIdEntities = createSelector(getLoadState, getSelectedMoveId, (loads: LogisticsLoad[], selectedMove: LogisticsMove) => {
   if (loads && selectedMove) {
       return loads.filter((load: LogisticsLoad) => load.LoadId === selectedMove.LoadId);
   } else {
       return loads;
   }
});
```

This approach wont work because it requires me to set a selectedMoveId in my state. There can be 100+ records showing on the page.

Comment: What about using `Observable.combineLatest()` in your component?

Comment: @joshvito Try to avoid creating selectors in your component. They're less performant and not easily reused.

Comment: How about using `Observable.combineLatest()` in a service then? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This approach wont work because it requires me to set a selectedMoveId in my state. There can be 100+ records showing on the page.

You can use this approach you've tried but with an array of `getCurrentMoveIds` instead of a single `getCurrentMoveId`. So there should be an array in your store containing the ids of those 100+ records you mention. Meanwhile try to use tiny selectors and combine those. An example approach:

```
const getCurrentMoves = createSelector(getCurrentMoveIds, getMoveEntities, (ids, entities) => ids.map(id => entities[id]));
const getCurrentMovesLoadIds = createSelector(getCurrentMoveEntities, (entities) => entities.map(entity => entity.load_id));
const getCurrentMoveLoads = createSelector(getCurrentMoveLoadIds, getLoadEntities, (ids, entities) => ids.map(id => entities[id]));
```

You could even merge those two arrays of entities in a selector if you'd like.

Comment: Do I have to have the array of getCurrentMoveIds? the getMoveEntities contain the selected moves already.

Comment: Not necessarily, but you'll need an array instead of an entity collection somewhere because it has a specific order. If the `getMoveEntities` actually is an array already that's fine of course.